# Criar arquivos pdf com pdBox

Tags: java

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando criar um arquivo PDF com o pdBox, gravando nele o que ele achar no matcher da minha aplicação, porem o pdf criado sai em branco alguém poderia me auxiliar nesta dúvida?

```
PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath()));
                    parser.parse();
                    COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
                    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                    PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
                    PrintWriter arq = new PrintWriter(new File("C:\\Tratados\\" + f.getName())); //Diretório de saida
                    //PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq);
                    List<String> linhasGravadas = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= pdDoc.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                        pdfStripper.setStartPage(i);
                        pdfStripper.setEndPage(i);
                        String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
                        String aut = "";
                        String hora = "";
                        String data = "";
                        int Aut = 0, Data = 0, Hora = 0;
                        System.out.println("Pagina: " + i);
                        arq.println("Pagina: " + i);
                        Matcher matcherData = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{4})"/*"\\b\\d{8}\\b"*/).matcher(parsedText);
                        Matcher matcherHora = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}[:|;]\\d{2}[:|;]\\d{2}").matcher(parsedText);
                        Matcher matcherAut = Pattern.compile(/*"\\s\\b\\d{9}\\b|*/"\\b\\d{9}\\b").matcher(parsedText);
                        int vAut = 0, vData = 0, vHora = 0;

                        if (!matcherAut.find()) {
                           System.out.println("Autorização: Não encontrado");
                           //arq.println("Autorização: Não encontrado");
                        } else {
                            //while (matcherAut.find()) {
                            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s^[0126789].*|^[0126789].*"); // Segundo Filtro (Elimina os que não começam com 3|4)
                            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(matcherAut.group()).useDelimiter(pattern);
                            Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(aut);
                            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                                aut = scanner.next();
                                if (!linhasGravadas.contains(aut)) {
                                    System.out.println("Autorização: " + matcherAut.group());
                                    arq.println("Autorização: " + matcherAut.group());
                                    Aut = Aut + 1;
                                }
                            }
                            //}
                        }
```

Comment: Esse artigo pode lhe ajudar a trabalhar com o pdBox:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzcLdUlVTrBtMzAwNzc4ODYtNjdjZS00MTQ5LTg2YTgtZjI2MTdlNDEzYWFm/view?pli=1

Comment: O problema é que pelo que vi o link só mostra como extrair dados e não como criar um arquivo